# How to to retrieve the user input values on the firebase database and then send an email to me?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am hosting my website on firebase. I also deployed this js file to firebase cloud functions.

How can I code it so that after the user enters something on a contact form on my website, the code will then retrieve the user input values on the database and then send an email to me?

Updated:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref("/contactData")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: "myemail@gmail.com",
                pass: "mypassword"
            }
        });

        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        const original = snapshot.val();

        console.log('sending email');
        console.log(original);

        const mailOptions = {
            from: val.email,
            to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        };

        mailOptions.subject = val.name + "  \n " + val.subject;
        mailOptions.text = val.message;

        console.log('Created entry', context.params.pushId, original);
        // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions
        // Your code ...
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error occurs!');
            } else {
                console.log('email sent!');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What isn't working about this code when you run/trigger it?

Comment: For some reason, it just doesn't run. I don't get any emails at all.

Comment: There are many things that could be going wrong, and you'll need to do some debugging yourself before we can say what's going on. Is the function being invoked when you check in the logging output? If so, are your `console.log` statements being printed? If so, what's the `val` being logged?

Comment: so I just added the rest of the code above. The console.log('successful login') is definitely being called when I check the firebase functions > logs, it says successful login. However, above that is also some stuff that I am not too sure what it means.

Comment: This is what it says :{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/peter-s-website/locations/us-central1/functions/sendEmailConfirmation"}

Comment: as for the val, is the text above the val that is being logged? I'm not too sure what val means. Thanks for the help btw! I really appreciate it

Comment: `val` refers to the value. Can you show the full log output of the execution of this function?

Comment: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"myemail@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/peter-s-website/locations/us-central1/functions/sendEmailConfirmation"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `onCreate` from the realtime database. From the question is not clear what `goMail` does. However, you should return a value or a promise in the Firebase Function.  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data)

```js
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('Email_Message/{mailId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Created entry', context.params.pushId, original);
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions
      // Your code ...
      return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try it out soon and get back to you

Comment: When you finish, please tell me how it did go!

Comment: Hey! Sorry fo the late reply, I was working on another project. I updated it but it is not working. I also tried using nodemailer? But the function exports.sendemailconfirmation doesnt seem to be being called at all in the console.log part on firebase.